# Out of memory when drawing a path on canvas that is much larger than the screen

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I have an Android view which is bigger than the visible portion of the view (e.g. 10000x6000 pixels) and I want to draw paths in the onDraw() method. Only paths which intersect the viewport are drawn and that works great most of the time but when the bounding box of the path being drawn gets much larger than the viewport, too much memory is allocated and crashes the app with an out of memory error. Even with the clip bounds set to the viewport, memory is allocated for the full area occupied by the bounding box of the path:

[image: Large canvas]

In the example above, the viewport is only 2000x1400 pixels but when the path is drawn on the canvas, memory is allocated to fit the full path (7000x4000 pixels = 112 MB).

Is there a way to limit the amount of memory allocated in this scenario?

BTW, iOS does limit the size of the rendered raster image when using clip bounds.

EDIT: looks like it's a known issue with hardware-rendered layers: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24023

Comment: I guess you are using the view ondraw method to draw your line I will runs in a main thread for refreshing the view

Comment: So use the surface view with separate thread to update your view will fix this issue mostly in gaming application uses the surface view for drawing the graphics

Comment: SurfaceView is overkill for what I need to do. And it doesn't solve the problem of the memory required for rendering a path that is larger than the screen.

Comment: A possible solution is to use a `Matrix` to scale the path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72504556/1124866

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this issue might not be the cleanest but did what i needed. I used canvas.drawLines, which lefts not connected intersections between each line but does work much smoothly.

```
float[] pathArray = new float[(nodes.size() - 1) * 4];
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size() - 1; i++) {
    int index = i * 4;

    Node from = nodes.get(i);
    pathArray[index] = from.x;
    pathArray[index + 1] = from.y;

    Node to = nodes.get(i + 1);
    pathArray[index + 2] = to.x;
    pathArray[index + 3] = to.y;
}
```

With this way we can create our "path".

then draw it to the canvas as below;

```
canvas.drawLines(pathArray, mDefaultPaint);
```

As i said outcome will be broken links between lines but there will be no oom issue

Answer (score -2):

Did you see this warning?

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Shape too large to be rendered into a texture (260x9197, max=8192x8192)
```

Comment: Yes, I see the warning. So what's the solution?

Comment: If the screen is not that big, the part beyond the screen will not be drawn. The specific scenarios still need to be analyzed in detail, and cannot be templated.